# How to test for one way correlation between time series?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I want to test existence of correlation between two time series but I suspect that there would exist only one way correlation. By one way, I mean that changes in Series A should bring about a change in Series B, but the converse may not be true.
Do any tests cater to this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Pearson's correlation is symmetric. Thus, the correlation of A with B equals the correlation of B with A. So on a certain construal of your question, it doesn't make sense.

However, perhaps you are referring to something like time lagged cross-correlations. E.g., a change in X correlates with a change in Y in the future but a change in Y may not necessarily correlate with a future change in X. You could look at [lagged cross-correlations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Time_series_analysis) and [Granger causality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality)

Comment: Actually its kinda opposite of what you suggested. X lags Y and I expect that a change in Y should show up as a change in X but a change in X may not always lead to a change in Y.

Comment: A little less abstractly, a change in X may change in response of more than one covariates. But only one of those covariates also leads to a change in Y.